# Setting up Session Variables

Tags: c#, session-variables

I have a RadioButtonList with 2 options
-Beach bach
-Bush bach

I want to create 2 session variables 
am I doing it right

```
Session["beachBach"] = bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue = "Beach bach";
Session["bushBach"] = bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue = "Bush bach";
```

so if users press chose the "Beach bach", 1 will be added to Session["beachBach"]
the same goes to Bush bach

or do I need to create 2 radiobuttonlist??

thanks

Comment: Hi, do you use the same radiobutton changing the selected value?

Comment: when you run the code specified above the Session["beachBach"] variable will concist the string "beach Bach" and not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `==` instead of `=`:

```
Session["beachBach"] = bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Beach bach";
Session["bushBach"] = bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Bush bach";
```

Otherwise you're setting the `SelectedValue` of each radio button then storing *that string* in the session variables.  If you use `==` you are *comparing* the values and storing `true` or `false` in the session variables.

If you *really* want to store `1` or `0` (which I don't recommend - `bool` values should work just fine and will make the server side code cleaner) just use the `(condition) ? (true) : (false)`  ternary operator:

```
Session["beachBach"] = bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Beach bach" ? 1 : 0;
Session["bushBach"] = bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Bush bach" ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to set a session variable depending on the selected value of the radiobuttonlist. For that you can do this:

```
// If bachRadioButtonList SelectedValue != "Beach bach",
// clear session variable, else set value to "Beach bach"
Session["beachBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue != "Beach bach") ? null : "Beach bach";

// If bachRadioButtonList SelectedValue != "Bush bach",
// clear session variable, else set value to "Bush bach"
Session["bushBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue != "Bush bach") ? null : "Bush bach";
```

Comment: hi, thanks for ur help but when i transfer those session variable to my other pages, it does not added 1 event if i chose 1 of the 2 options :(

Comment: how can i message a part of my code to you...so you can help me out  :(.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the value `1` (which your code won't do), you should store a boolean value (either `true` or `false`).

```
Session["beachBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Beach bach");
Session["bushBach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Bush bach");
```

However, you'll have to carry two session variables and it's not really great. If someday you have 50 radiobuttons, you don't really want 50 session variables. Instead, you can create an enum and fit into the session variable the choice you want :

```
public enum BachEnum 
{
    Beach,
    Bush
}

Session["bach"] = (bachRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "Beach bach") ? BachEnum.Beach : BachEnum.Beach;
```

You can then extend your enum with new values, and conditions can be done like this :

```
if ((BachEnum)Session["bach"] == BachEnum.Beach)
    // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You ahould use selectedIndexChange event.

```
void SelectedIndex_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

   Session["SelValue"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

In any case, I don't know what do you want to achieve, but I'm pretty sure you should consider not using two single session variables for this.

Answer (score -1):

You create two radio button list if the values are not mutually exclusive. I they are, the they must be in the same list to ensure only one of both is selected at a time.

Comment: hi, what do you means,